# How to force qsv generate idr when using qsv encoding in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I use h264_qsv to encode video, and it works, the video can be translated to be h264.
But how to force it to generate IDR frame? I use the following code:

```
encodeFrame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I;
int ret = avcodec_send_frame(m_ctx, encodeFrame);
```

but no idr frame was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QSV encoders have a private option to enable IDR frames when the frame is signaled as a I-frame.

Add before opening the encoder.

```
av_opt_set(m_ctx->priv_data, "forced_idr", "1", 0);
```

Comment: Although it can generate idr, but why is the latency of video to be  larger?

Comment: That's a different Q.

Comment: @Gyan Setting 'forced_idr' to 1 is useful, but once I set a AVFrame's 'pict_type' to AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I, the subsequent frames are encoded as idr frames...What I want is that the frame I set 'pict_type' to AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I is encoded as an idr frame, the subsequent frames I set 'pict_type' to AV_PICTURE_TYPE_P are encoded as an none idr frame.

Comment: It seems a bug of ffmpeg, and I found the solution: http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2021-January/274342.html